What is the analogy of fall back after mismatch between when using LPS table vs when calculating LPS table itself?
I understand the main part of KMP algorithm relatively well, which is to fall back when mismatch occurs according to LPS table.
However, I always get so confused about the fall back when calculate/create the LPS table itself, that is, what would be the text and pattern, respectively, in that case? could anyone share me some core intuitions behind it to help me better understand it?

The Wikipedia article on KMP has a nice explanation.

The way I understand it, the high-level idea is that if you're searching a (large) body of text for "ABRACADABRA", say, and the current test fails at the "C", then knowing that the previous 4 characters matched, the next possible match must start at the last "A" in "ABRA" since neither "B" nor "R" is an "A". -- Generally, the table says if you fail at position i+iw in the word, start next match attempt at i + table[iw] rather than at i + 1.

Hi fellow, many thanks for you comment. I comprehend how the LPS table is used to help fall back more wisely when mismatch occurs, my confusion is solely on how the fall back works when calculate LPS itself.

After some hard pondering I guess I finally got my light bulb moment.
The analogy is, when calculating the LPS table, we are effectively trying to match the text, which is the last n+1 characters aka suffix, with the pattern, which is the first n+1 characters aka prefix, where n is the length already matched, and the LPS table for this analogy is the partial LPS created so far.
Take s="AABAACAABAAB" as an example, when trying to match the last char 'B' with s[5], we are actually trying to match text "AABAAB" with pattern "AABAAC", now mismatch occurs, then, instead of returning back to the very first char, we return to the s[LPS[5-1]], which is 2.
